# Reference a programmatically added Framelayout (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I'm new to android development so this might be pretty straightforward. However, I couldn't find anything that worked for me.

I've managed to successfully add multiple framelayouts to a linear layout through the following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    LinearLayout fragmentContainer=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
    fragmentContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


    //if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

    for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
        //create a new TextFrag object
        TextFrag textFragment=new TextFrag();

        //pass arguments to the textFrag Object with the Fragment Number
        Bundle args=new Bundle();
        args.putInt("FragNumber", i);
        textFragment.setArguments(args);

        //Create a new Frame Layout for Each Fragment. This is useful if you want to switch fragments at runtime
        //Dont know exact details yet
        FrameLayout fragmentFrame=new FrameLayout(this);
        //set a unique id for the FrameLayout
        fragmentFrame.setId(i); 

        //Define the Frame Layout Params
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);




        //Add the Fragment to the Frame Layout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(fragmentFrame.getId(),textFragment).commit();



        //Add the Frame Layout to the Linear Layout
        fragmentContainer.addView(fragmentFrame);


    }



}
```

So at some point later in the program I'd like to reference these framelayouts and I figured since I knew the IDs I could just use getViewById.

This doesn't seem to work though. I've only slightly modified the above code by adding a redundant FrameLayout object called testFrame as below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    LinearLayout fragmentContainer=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
    fragmentContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


    //if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

    for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
        //create a new TextFrag object
        TextFrag textFragment=new TextFrag();

        //pass arguments to the textFrag Object with the Fragment Number
        Bundle args=new Bundle();
        args.putInt("FragNumber", i);
        textFragment.setArguments(args);

        //Create a new Frame Layout for Each Fragment. This is useful if you want to switch fragments at runtime
        //Dont know exact details yet
        FrameLayout fragmentFrame=new FrameLayout(this);
        //set a unique id for the FrameLayout
        fragmentFrame.setId(i); 

        //Define the Frame Layout Params
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params=new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        //CHANGED CODE STARTS HERE

        int theId=i;

        FrameLayout testFrame=(FrameLayout) findViewById(theId);

        if(testFrame!=null){

        //Add the Fragment to the Frame Layout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(testFrame.getId(),textFragment).commit();



        //Add the Frame Layout to the Linear Layout
        fragmentContainer.addView(testFrame);
        }

        //CHANGED CODE ENDS HERE

    }



}
```

So basically, it shows none of the framelayouts anymore because the testFrame object is now null. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that you look for the `FrameLayout` with the loop id **before** you actually add the `FrameLayout` to the container(`fragmentContainer.addView(testFrame);`) which will obviously fail to find any views.

Comment: wow thanks that worked! Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Luksprog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/493939/luksprog) for the answer. Simple creating an element and assigning an id to it is not enough. It needs to be added to an existing view that is referenced in the R file. In my case the existing view was R.id.fragment_container